# I made a text base game but my code won't work

Tags: python

I made a text-based Zombie game for class, but my code isn't working.

My code:

```py
rooms = {
    'Master Bedroom': {'South': 'Kitchen', 'North': 'Toy Room', 'East': 'Garage', 'West': 'Closet'},
    'Kitchen': {'North': 'Master Bedroom', 'East': 'Bathroom', 'West': 'Backyard', 'Item': 'Cell Phone'},
    'Gun Room': {'South': 'Closet', 'East': 'Toy room', 'Item': 'Pistol'},
    'Backyard': {'East': 'Kitchen', 'Item': 'ZOMBIE'},
    'Garage': {'West': 'Master Bedroom', 'South': 'Bathroom', 'Item': 'Body Armor'},
    'Toy Room': {'South': 'Master Bedroom', 'West': 'Gun Room', 'Item': 'Baseball Bat'},
    'Closet': {'East': 'Master Bedroom', 'North': 'Gun Room', 'Item': 'Flashlight'},
    'Bathroom': {'North': 'Garage', 'West': 'Kitchen', 'Item': 'Bandages'}
}


def get_item(state):
    if state != 'Master Bedroom':
        return ' a' + rooms[state]['Item']
    else:
        return 'Nothing'


print('You see',)  # print


def get_item(state):
    return rooms[state]['Item']


def show_instructions():
    print('ZOMBIE run Adventure Game')
    print('Collect 6 items to win the game, or be eaten by a ZOMBIE.')
    print('Move commands: go South, go North, go East, go West')
    print("Add to Inventory: get 'Item_name'")
    print("type quit to end the game")


show_instructions()  # calling Function
inventory = []

state = 'Master Bedroom'
while True:
    print('You are in', state)  # printing state
    print('Inventory:', inventory)  # printing inventory
    item = get_item(state)  # calling get_item function
    print('You see a ', item)  # print
    print('--------------------')
    if item == 'ZOMBIE':
        print('NOM NOM...GAME OVER!')
        exit(0)

    direction = input('Enter your move:')
    if direction == 'go East' or direction == 'go West' or direction == 'go North' or direction == 'go South':  # if
        direction = direction[3:]
        if (new_state := rooms[state].get(direction)) is None:
            print('The room has wall in that direction enter other direction!')
        else:
            state = new_state
    elif direction.startswith('get ') and len(direction) > 4:
        item_name = direction[4:]
        if item_name == item and item_name not in inventory:
            inventory.append(item)
        else:
            print('That item could not be taken at this location.')
    else:
        print('Invalid direction!')

    if len(inventory) == 6:
        print('Congratulations! You have collected all items and defeated the ZOMBIE!')
        exit(0)

stop = "go"

while stop != 'quit':
    show_instructions()
    user_input = input("what would you like to do?")
    if user_input == 'quit':
        break
```

**These are the errors I am getting:**
Unresolved reference 'inventory':60
Unresolved reference 'inventory':63
Redeclared 'get_item' defined above without usage:26
Name 'state' can be undefined:42
This code is unreachable:71
Shadows name 'state' from outer scope:15
PEP 8: E303 too many blank lines (3):26
Shadows name 'state' from outer scope:26

Comment: Please show the full error message. That includes the entire TraceBack.

Comment: What makes you think  that `rooms[state]` (in this case `rooms[Master Bedroom]`) should have an entry with the key `'Item'`?

Comment: `Unresolved reference 'inventory':60` I don't see how this is possible with this code.  And certainly not on line 60, which is an `else` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You have get_item defined twice.

```
def get_item(state):
    if state != 'Master Bedroom':
        return ' a' + rooms[state]['Item']
    else:
        return 'Nothing'


print('You see',)  # print


def get_item(state):
    return rooms[state]['Item']
```

The second definition overrides the first, and then since there is no Item key for Master Bedroom it throws an error